# Why does ByteBuddy route method delegation to the "wrong" method in this scenario?

Tags: byte-buddy

I am putting together a very simple ByteBuddy delegate/proxy class.

The intention is (again, very simple) to proxy a class such that any of its non-`final`, non-`private`, non-`static` methods and so forth get routed to equivalent methods on its `proxiedInstance` field as returned by its `getProxiedInstance` method.  (There should be exceptions made for the usual suspects: `equals`, `hashCode`, `wait` and `notify` and so on.)

I've set up my proxy class using the subclass strategy.  I've also defined two methods, `getProxiedInstance` and `setProxiedInstance`, along with a `private` field named `proxiedInstance` of the proper type.  I've done this using the `FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty()` strategy.  I've omitted that here for brevity and clarity.  The class does in fact contain this field and these two methods.

Then I've defined the method interception like this, statically importing the relevant `ElementMatchers` methods:

```
builder
      .method(not(isFinal()).and(not(isStatic())).and(not(isPrivate()))
              .and((isPublic().and(named("toString")).and(takesArguments(0)).and(returns(String.class)))
                   .or((not(isDeclaredBy(Object.class)).and(not(named("getProxiedInstance"))).and(not(named("setProxiedInstance"))))))
              )
      .intercept(MethodDelegation.toMethodReturnOf("getProxiedInstance"));
```

In English: not `final`, not `static`, not `private`, and *either* the `public String toString()` method inherited from `Object` (or overridden), *or* any other method not declared by `Object.class` and not named `getProxiedInstance` or `setProxiedInstance`.

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
public class Frob {

  public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello!";
  }

}
```

When I create a proxy class for it, instantiate it, and then call `toString()` on the proxy, I get `Hello!`.

This suggests to me somehow that the recipe I've quoted above is somehow routing `toString()` to `sayHello()`.

From reading the `MethodDelegation` javadocs, it seems that maybe `sayHello` on the target/delegate object is picked for delegation because it is more specific than the method invoked on the proxy (`toString`).  I guess name matching is lower priority than that.

I think this use case I have is relatively simple.  How do I best accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

The best I could do, which works, but seems perhaps a little clunky or verbose, was this:

```
builder = builder
      .method(not(isDeclaredBy(Object.class))
              .and(not(isFinal()))
              .and(not(isStatic()))
              .and(not(isPrivate()))
              .and(not(named("getProxiedInstance")))
              .and(not(named("setProxiedInstance"))))
      .intercept(MethodDelegation.toMethodReturnOf("getProxiedInstance"))
      .method(is(toStringMethod))
      .intercept(invoke(toStringMethod).onMethodCall(invoke(named("getProxiedInstance"))));
```

(`toStringMethod` is the `Method` resulting from `Object.class.getMethod("toString")`.)

Answer (score 1):

I think using `MethodCall` is a better approach to this. `MethodDelegation` is meant for "catch all proxies" where you inject corresponding dispatchers into what is often a single delegate method, maybe two. Method call is also much more performance since it does not need to do the analysis but just reroutes to a method of a compatible type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My understanding is with `MethodCall`, however, I have to know what method to call.  Is there some recipe using the fluent API that I am unaware of that says, "if the user called `x`, invoke `x` on the `proxiedInstance`"?

Comment: In other words: I don't know what method the user is going to call on the dynamic type.  When she calls that method, whatever it is, I want to call an equivalent method on the return value of `getProxiedInstance`.  `MethodCall.invoke(ElementMatcher)` seems to work on the _instrumented_ type, and I don't see an `ElementMatcher` that matches "whatever the user called originally".

Comment: That's what MethodCall does. Invoke the invoked methods on a field for example.

Comment: OK; which static `MethodCall` method should I start with?  Sorry to be so stupid!

Comment: I've tried to do my homework here; https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-dep/src/test/java/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCallTest.java though shows only usages where the argument to `invoke` is known in advance.  That's not my case.

Comment: My latest interception recipe is: `.intercept(MethodCall.invoke(MethodCall.MethodLocator.ForInstrumentedMethod.INSTANCE).onMethodCall(invoke(named("getProxiedInstance"))))`.  Was that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, it does; thank you!  Please consider adding this explicitly to documentation somewhere as using that static `INSTANCE` field was far from obvious in this situation. Thanks again!

Comment: It'd be more common to run MethodCall.invokeSelf().

Comment: Ah; great; so the documentation about it being a recursive invocation does not apply in this case?

Comment: It mentions that you need to change the target of the method call via `.on` which is what you do.